# API call to crypto.com in node returns invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I'm sending a POST request to the crypto.com public API ([reference](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html?javascript#introduction)) using `node-fetch`. More specifically, I'm am attempting to call the private method [get-account-summary](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html?javascript#private-get-account-summary) and I am signing the request beforehand with my API Key and my Secret Key as prescribed on their API reference page (see [digital signature](https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html?javascript#digital-signature)).

```js
const requestBody = JSON.stringify(signRequest(request, apiKey, apiSecret));

fetch('https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: requestBody
})
.then(response => response.body)
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

The request is apparently successful, but I'm struggling to make sense of the API response which is supposed to look like this:

```json
{
    "id": 11,
    "method": "private/get-account-summary",
    "code": 0,
    "result": {
        "accounts": [
            {
                "balance": 99999999.905000000000000000,
                "available": 99999996.905000000000000000,
                "order": 3.000000000000000000,
                "stake": 0,
                "currency": "CRO"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but this is what I actually get:

```json
Success: PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: true,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    dataEmitted: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
    error: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: true,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: true,
    ended: true,
    finished: true,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    buffered: [],
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    allBuffers: true,
    allNoop: true,
    pendingcb: 0,
    constructed: true,
    prefinished: true,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
  },
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
}
```

You may have noticed that I logged the `response.body` to the console rather than the `response.json()` because whenever I call the latter, I get an "invalid json error"

> ```
> Error: FetchError: invalid json response body at
> https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary reason:
> Unexpected end of JSON input
>     at C:\Users\...\app\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:273:32
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
>   type: 'invalid-json'
> ```

Comment: "This is what I actually get" - that's not valid JSON.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what could cause the API to respond with what's clearly not valid JSON?

Comment: I have the feeling that's not actually what the API responded with, but rather what your component is responding with. Look at the Network tab on the Developer Tools of your browser and look at the raw response.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not communicating anything to the client, running on localhost but all I've got is what I log to the console (Windows command line). How would I test this in the browser?

Comment: Oh, right, node.js. You'll need to use Fiddler or Wireshark or something like that.

Comment: The thing you show as a response looks like a state object. Which makes sense since `response.body` is a `ReadableStream`. See [`Response.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body) for info on how to process that. You might actually want [`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text).

Comment: @Ouroborus `response.text()` produces nothing, literally empty space in cmd: `Success:      `

Comment: try logging response.ok response.status response.headers.get('content-type') ...

Comment: @cmgchess `response.ok` returns `true`, `response.status` returns `200`, BUT `response.headers.get('content-type')` returns `null` for some reason...

Comment: Do you get the correct result following this pattern from the fetch api notes `const response = await fetch('...', {method: 'POST', body: '...'});
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);`?

Comment: @KScandrett using `await fetch` made no difference

Comment: @Aaronv I added an answer. I hope it helps as per the problem statement you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI this issue had nothing to do with the way in which the API request was made, it was related to the signing of the request body instead (which is not mentioned in the question); the `signRequest(...)` method that is passed as an argument to the `fetch` method after being stringified, does not actually return any values but instead mutates the request argument. Once I accounted for this, the API call was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Many API stacks work in terms of 2 promises:

- Make the remote request
- Deserialize the response

According to [docs](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#post-with-json) you need to await the `.json()` call.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
const data = await response.json();
```

Nested promises looks messier when using `then`, which is why many people prefer the
async await syntax, but this will work:

```js
request('https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary', {
  json: true,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: requestBody
})
.then(response => {
   response.json()
       .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in a previous comment (see comment thread directly below my question), using `await fetch` results in the same error: `unexpected end of JSON input`

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a response stream. A simpler approach would be to use npm `request` package.

**Ex :**

```
const request = require('request');
const requestBody = JSON.stringify(signRequest(request, apiKey, apiSecret));

request('https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary', {
  json: true,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: requestBody
})
.then(response => response.body)
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sorry I missed the end of the question. If `json()` is invalid and the `text()` returns nothing, I would say you should check your request body. The request is successful, but you get an empty response.

Not sure why you are using `response.body`. You need to use `json()` if you want the response in a JSON format. This will take the body and return a promise which resolve to the requested format. You can read it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#bodyjson).

So, your code should look like this:

```
fetch('https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: requestBody
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```